# Why do tasks in the same task set have very different execution time?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm doing some kind of string processing on Spark. My code snippet:

```
val rdd = sc.objectFile[(String, String)]("some hdfs url", 1);
rdd.cache.count // let cache happen

val combOp = (f: List[String], g: List[String]) => {
  for (x <- f) {
    finder.processEntry(x)
  }
  for (x <- g) {
    finder.processEntry(x)
  }
  finder.result
}


val res = rdd.mapPartitions( x => {
  for (e<-x) {
    finder.processEntry(e)
  }
  Iterator(finder.result)
}, true).reduce(combOp)
```

The dataset I have is about 10GB. I'm running Spark on a 24 cores machine, with 48GB memory. Configure file:

```
spark.driver.memory 1g
spark.executor.memory 30g
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions -Xloggc:/var/log/gcmemory.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails
spark.executor.cores 4
```

Execution log snippet:

```
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.60.1.143:42850 with 15.5 GB RAM, BlockManagerId(0, 10.60.1.143, 42850)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 1766.0 B, free: 15.5 GB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 16.8 KB, free: 15.5 GB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_3 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 219.7 MB, free: 15.3 GB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_1 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 229.7 MB, free: 15.1 GB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_2 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 221.5 MB, free: 14.9 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) in 6345 ms on 10.60.1.143 (1/34)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2) in 6351 ms on 10.60.1.143 (2/34)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 6354 ms on 10.60.1.143 (3/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_0 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 220.6 MB, free: 14.7 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 6454 ms on 10.60.1.143 (4/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_5 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 219.9 MB, free: 14.4 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 8.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 8, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 5.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 5) in 2287 ms on 10.60.1.143 (5/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_4 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 222.7 MB, free: 14.2 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 9.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_6 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 210.7 MB, free: 14.0 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) in 2350 ms on 10.60.1.143 (6/34)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6) in 2356 ms on 10.60.1.143 (7/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_7 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 214.6 MB, free: 13.8 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 11.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 11, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7) in 2289 ms on 10.60.1.143 (8/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_8 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 216.3 MB, free: 13.6 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 12.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 12, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 8.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 8) in 2430 ms on 10.60.1.143 (9/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_11 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 216.5 MB, free: 13.4 GB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_10 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 216.5 MB, free: 13.2 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 11.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 11) in 2416 ms on 10.60.1.143 (10/34)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 14.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 14, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 10.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 10) in 2445 ms on 10.60.1.143 (11/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_9 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 231.4 MB, free: 12.9 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 15.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 15, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 9.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 9) in 2528 ms on 10.60.1.143 (12/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_12 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 217.3 MB, free: 12.7 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 16.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 16, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 12.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 12) in 1797 ms on 10.60.1.143 (13/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_14 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 215.8 MB, free: 12.5 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 17.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 17, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 14.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 14) in 1748 ms on 10.60.1.143 (14/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_13 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 220.9 MB, free: 12.3 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 13.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 13) in 1812 ms on 10.60.1.143 (15/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_15 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 233.8 MB, free: 12.1 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 19.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 19, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 15.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 15) in 1756 ms on 10.60.1.143 (16/34)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_16 in memory on 10.60.1.143:42850 (size: 221.6 MB, free: 11.9 GB)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 20.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 20, 10.60.1.143, ANY, 1642 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 16.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 16) in 2600 ms on 10.60.1.143 (17/34)
```

How can the first runners in the same task set execute longer than its latter runners? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution? If so, please post it.

Answer (score 0):

A common cause for stragglers (or executors that take longer for a certain partitions than others) is unevenly partitioner data. I'd suggest trying to repartition your data. The Spark UI may also have some helpful information (you can take a look at the input sizes etc.) Sometimes some machines are slower for random reasons (especially common in virtualized environments where we can have noisy neighbors on  certain machines), you can try enabling speculative execution (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) / set the `spark.speculation` flag so Spark can try and solve the problem on another executor if it happens to be running slowly on one machine.

Comment: I'm sure the data is partitioned evenly, and it runs on a single SMP machine so there is no noisy neighbores. I wonder it may be JVM classloader's overhead.